# Laravel 8: Unable to show and edit individual content

Tags: crud, laravel-8

I created a basic CRUD site using Laravel 8.

The created app is able to list data from a local MySQL database and create a new object, but it cannot show the details, edit and delete an object. The error shown on the Edit page is:

> Missing required parameter for [Route: tasks.update] [URI: tasks/{task}] [Missing parameter: task]. (View: /Users/adv/Documents/workspace/unlocker/hobbs-admin/resources/views/tasks/edit.blade.php)

I use `var_dump($hobbsTask)` in the `edit.blade.php` and found the the `HobbsTask` object is empty. How come?

On the other hand, the `show.blade.php` shows no data at all. Seems it's the same issue as the Edit page. What did I miss?

---

The codes are as follow:

**app/Http/Controllers/HobbsTaskController**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Models\HobbsTask;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class HobbsTaskController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        $tasks = HobbsTask::latest()->paginate(5);
        return view('tasks.index', compact('tasks'))
            ->with('i', (request()->input('page', 1) - 1) * 5);
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function create()
    {
        return view('tasks.create');
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $request->validate([
            'session_name' => 'required',
            'pid' => 'required',
            'file_path' => 'required',
            'file_type' => 'required',
            'file_size' => 'required'
        ]);

        HobbsTask::create($request->all());

        return redirect()->route('tasks.index')
            ->with('success', 'Task created successfully.');
    }

    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  \App\Models\HobbsTask  $hobbsTask
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function show(HobbsTask $hobbsTask)
    {
        return view('tasks.show', compact('hobbsTask'));
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  \App\Models\HobbsTask  $hobbsTask
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function edit(HobbsTask $hobbsTask)
    {
        return view('tasks.edit', compact('hobbsTask'));
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \App\Models\HobbsTask  $hobbsTask
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function update(Request $request, HobbsTask $hobbsTask)
    {
        $request->validate([
            'session_name' => 'required'
        ]);

        $hobbsTask->update($request->all());

        return redirect()->route('tasks.index')
            ->with('success', 'Task updated successfully');
    }

    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     *
     * @param  \App\Models\HobbsTask  $hobbsTask
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function destroy(HobbsTask $hobbsTask)
    {
        $hobbsTask->delete();
        return redirect()->route('tasks.index')
            ->with('success', 'Task deleted successfully');
    }
}
```

**app/Models/HobbsTask.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class HobbsTask extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $table = 'unlocker_tickets';
    public $timestamps = true;

    protected $fillable = [
        'pid',
        'session_name',
        'file_type',
        'file_path',
        'file_size'
    ];
}
```

**resources/views/Tasks/Index.blade.php**

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12 margin-tb">
        <div class="pull-left">
            <h2>Laravel 8 CRUD Example </h2>
        </div>
        <div class="pull-right">
            <a class="btn btn-success" href="{{ route('tasks.create') }}" title="Create a task"> <i class="fas fa-plus-circle"></i>
                </a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

@if ($message = Session::get('success'))
    <div class="alert alert-success">
        <p>{{ $message }}</p>
    </div>
@endif

<table class="table table-bordered table-responsive-lg">
    <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Session Name</th>
        <th>PID</th>
        <th>File Path</th>
        <th>File Type</th>
        <th>File Size</th>
        <th>Date Created</th>
        <th>Actions</th>
    </tr>
    @foreach ($tasks as $task)
        <tr>
            <td>{{ $task->id }}</td>
            <td>{{ $task->session_name }}</td>
            <td>{{ $task->pid }}</td>
            <td>{{ $task->file_path }}</td>
            <td>{{ $task->file_type }}</td>
            <td>{{ $task->file_size }}</td>
            <td>{{ date_format($task->created_at, 'jS M Y') }}</td>
            <td>
                <form action="{{ route('tasks.destroy', $task->id) }}" method="POST">
                    <a href="{{ route('tasks.show', $task->id) }}" title="show">
                        <i class="fas fa-eye text-success fa-lg"></i>
                    </a>
                    <a href="{{ route('tasks.edit', $task->id) }}">
                        <i class="fas fa-edit fa-lg"></i>
                    </a>

                    @csrf
                    @method('DELETE')

                    <button type="submit" title="delete" style="border: none; background-color:transparent;">
                        <i class="fas fa-trash fa-lg text-danger"></i>
                    </button>
                </form>
            </td>
        </tr>
    @endforeach
</table>

{!! $tasks->links() !!}

@endsection
```

**resources/views/Tasks/edit.blade.php**

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12 margin-tb">
            <div class="pull-left">
                <h2>Edit Task</h2>
            </div>
            <div class="pull-right">
                <a class="btn btn-primary" href="{{ route('tasks.index') }}" title="Go back"> <i class="fas fa-backward "></i> </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    @if ($errors->any())
        <div class="alert alert-danger">
            <strong>Error!</strong>
            <ul>
                @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
                    <li>{{ $error }}</li>
                @endforeach
            </ul>
        </div>
    @endif

    <form action="{{ route('tasks.update', $hobbsTask->id) }}" method="POST">
        @csrf
        @method('PUT')

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <strong>Session Name:</strong>
                    <input type="text" name="session_name" class="form-control" value="{{ $hobbsTask->session_name }}">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <strong>PID:</strong>
                    <input type="number" name="pid" value="{{ $hobbsTask->pid }}" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <strong>File Path:</strong>
                    <input type="text" name="file_path" class="form-control" value="{{ $hobbsTask->file_path }}">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <strong>File Type:</strong>
                    <input type="text" name="file_type" class="form-control" value="{{ $hobbsTask->file_type }}">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <strong>File Size:</strong>
                    <input type="number" name="file_size" value="{{ $hobbsTask->file_size }}" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 text-center">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
            </div>
        </div>

    </form>
@endsection
```

**resources/views/Tasks/show.blade.php**

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12 margin-tb">
            <div class="pull-left">
                <h2>{{ $hobbsTask->session_name }}</h2>
            </div>
            <div class="pull-right">
                <a class="btn btn-primary" href="{{ route('tasks.index') }}" title="Go back"> <i class="fas fa-backward "></i> </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">
            <div class="form-group">
                <strong>Session Name:</strong>
                {{ $hobbsTask->session_name }}
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">
            <div class="form-group">
                <strong>PID:</strong>
                {{ $hobbsTask->pid }}
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">
            <div class="form-group">
                <strong>File Path:</strong>
                {{ $hobbsTask->file_path }}
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">
            <div class="form-group">
                <strong>File Type:</strong>
                {{ $hobbsTask->file_type }}
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">
            <div class="form-group">
                <strong>File Size:</strong>
                {{ $hobbsTask->file_size }}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
@endsection
```

**routes/web.php**

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use App\Http\Controllers\HobbsTaskController;

Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

Route::resource('tasks', HobbsTaskController::class);
```

Routing information:

```
% php artisan route:list


+--------+-----------+-------------------+---------------+--------------------------------------------------+------------+
| Domain | Method    | URI               | Name          | Action                                           | Middleware |
+--------+-----------+-------------------+---------------+--------------------------------------------------+------------+
|        | GET|HEAD  | /                 |               | Closure                                          | web        |
|        | GET|HEAD  | api/user          |               | Closure                                          | api        |
|        |           |                   |               |                                                  | auth:api   |
|        | GET|HEAD  | tasks             | tasks.index   | App\Http\Controllers\HobbsTaskController@index   | web        |
|        | POST      | tasks             | tasks.store   | App\Http\Controllers\HobbsTaskController@store   | web        |
|        | GET|HEAD  | tasks/create      | tasks.create  | App\Http\Controllers\HobbsTaskController@create  | web        |
|        | GET|HEAD  | tasks/{task}      | tasks.show    | App\Http\Controllers\HobbsTaskController@show    | web        |
|        | PUT|PATCH | tasks/{task}      | tasks.update  | App\Http\Controllers\HobbsTaskController@update  | web        |
|        | DELETE    | tasks/{task}      | tasks.destroy | App\Http\Controllers\HobbsTaskController@destroy | web        |
|        | GET|HEAD  | tasks/{task}/edit | tasks.edit    | App\Http\Controllers\HobbsTaskController@edit    | web        |
+--------+-----------+-------------------+---------------+--------------------------------------------------+------------+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because your route parameter name is a task.

You need to replace $hobbsTask to $task
in edit and show function.

You can do it like this

```
public function show(HobbsTask $task)
 {
        $hobbsTask = $task;
        return view('tasks.show',compact('hobbsTask'));
 }
```

```
public function edit(HobbsTask $task)
{
      $hobbsTask = $task;
      return view('tasks.edit', compact('hobbsTask'));
}
```

Comment: It works. I wonder why the `make:controller` command generated wrong template.